# Create a io.Reader from a local file

Tags: go

I would like to open a local file, and return a `io.Reader`. The reason is that I need to feed a `io.Reader` to a library I am using, like:

```
func read(r io.Reader) (results []string) {

}
```

Comment: Probably worth spending some time browsing around http://golang.org/pkg/ and, for the kind of thing it sounds like you're doing, the os, io, io/ioutil, and bufio.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

`os.Open` returns an `io.Reader`

http://play.golang.org/p/BskGT09kxL

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

var _ io.Reader = (*os.File)(nil)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Comment: Heh, love the trick for showing that (*os.File) is an io.Reader without being able to Open files from the Playground.

Comment: @twotwotwo what exactly does that hack do. I am assuming syntacticly it's saying a file of nothing so it never trys to open anything.

Comment: @mschuett More or less: it's a `nil` pointer of the right type to point to an `os.File`.  (In this case, you can't really do anything through it.) And the `var _ io.Reader = (*os.File)(nil)` assignment makes the compiler check that `*os.File` is an `io.Reader` (or else the assignment wouldn't be valid). If you go to the Playground and change `*os.File` to `*os.Process` you'll see the error it generates for things that don't satisfy the interface.

Comment: @fabrizioM where exactly in the documentation it says that *os.File implements a Reader. Otherwise, without this answer how you could figure out yourself from just reading an official doc? Ok, I see that `func (f *File) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)`, the same as in `Reader`.

Comment: I think the example is too contrived to provide a solid answer. Answer suggests using os.Open(), but the example does not it, at least not in an obvious way, as one would expect from an example.

Comment: @tutiplain This is a common pattern to ensure an interface is implemented properly. But a bit more explanation for beginners wouldn't harm, that's right.

Answer (score 56):

Use [os.Open()](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open):

> func Open(name string) (file *File, err error)
>
> Open opens the named
>   file for reading. If successful, methods on the returned file can be
>   used for reading; the associated file descriptor has mode O_RDONLY. If
>   there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

The returned value of type `*os.File` implements the `io.Reader` interface.

Answer (score 42):

The type *os.File implements the io.Reader interface, so you can return the file as a Reader.
But I recommend you to use the [bufio](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio) package if you have intentions of read big files, something like this:

```
file, err := os.Open("path/file.ext")
// if err != nil { ... }

return bufio.NewReader(file)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you recommend `bufio` for large files?

Comment: @CiroCosta if you have a huge file of Gbs you don't want to read it completely on memory, so for those cases we should use a buffer

Comment: go's runtime uses buffers in sensible situations e.g. [io.Copy](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=12784:12844#L353) will reuse underlying buffers if their interface is available - otherwise it will create an internal buffer

Comment: Thanks for `path/file.ext`. No other answer spelled out what `os.File` was.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example where we open a text file and create an io.Reader from the returned *os.File instance f

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("somefile.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    var r io.Reader
    r = f
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to do `r = f`? Isn't `f` already a reader?

Comment: Not that I can see from the golang source: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.7:src/os/types.go;l=16 but the above comment says that it implements the io.Reader interface so maybe yes

Answer (score 0):

io.Reader is an interface, it`s doccument is here [io.Reader](https://pkg.go.dev/io@go1.21.1#Reader), and the [os.File](https://pkg.go.dev/os@go1.21.1#File.Read) implement this interface, so you can read an File struct to get an io.Reader.

the code example is :

```golang
package main

import (
 "os"
)

func main() {
 file, err := os.Read("example.txt")
 ...
 // the `file` is an io.Reader
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just use the file object returned from, say, `os.Open` as a reader. I believe this type discipline is called "Duck Typing". For example, in the go tour reader [Exercise: rot13Reader](https://go.dev/tour/methods/23) you can replace the `main()` with this:

```
func main() {
   file, err := os.Open("file.txt") // For read access.
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }

   r := rot13Reader{file}
   io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```