# Encoding/Decoding a Gif

Tags: go, gif

I will be working on a project connected with GIF images and I tried to do some basic operations on them in Go (such as retrieving frames or creating GIF from a bunch of images). But for now let's do a  simple example in which I am only trying to decode a GIF and then to encode it again. I tried to use `"image/gif"` package, but I am unable to get it to do what I want.
Here is the code :

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "image/gif"
)


func main() {
    inputFile , err := os.Open("travolta.gif")
    defer inputFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    g, err := gif.DecodeAll(inputFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    outputFile, err := os.OpenFile("travolta2.gif", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
    defer outputFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = gif.EncodeAll(outputFile, g)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

When I run the code it does not panic and another gif is indeed created. Unfortunetely it is corrupted. Moreover the gif's size changes from 3,4MB to 4,4MB. Is it not a way to save/read a gif? What mistake do I make?

**EDIT:**
By corrupted I mean that when I try to open it an error occurs- screnshot here : http://www.filedropper.com/obrazekpociety.

GIF: 
http://vader.joemonster.org/upload/rwu/1539970c1d48acceLw7m.gif

Go version 1.7.4

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupted"? What version of Go are you using? Can you provide a sample of a file that doesn't work?

Comment: I have editted the question

Comment: Are you certain that this is the _exact_ code and image you're using? The image you provided is 9.2MB, not 3.4. This should work correctly with go1.7 and go1.8. (side note, always check the error _before_ deferring a Close, or you can get panics)

Comment: Damn I was checking a lot of gifs and must have overwritten the one i mentioned earlier. But this one does not work as well. I will try to find the old gif. 100℅ sure it is the same code

Comment: Should be this one: http://vader.joemonster.org/upload/rwu/1539970c1d48acceLw7m.gif

Comment: This gif is _technically_ corrupt to start (LZW string table overflow), which is likely what's causing problems. Most decoders ignore this, but some will error out. Having Go decode and encode the gif however seems to "fix" this issue, so I'm note sure what problem you're seeing. As for the size discrepancy, it's a different encoder, so the size isn't guaranteed to be exactly the same.

Comment: So my code does produce a correct, readable GIF on your pc?

Comment: yes, with go1.7 and go1.8, but only on amd64. Not sure if i386 causes the overflow to be handled differently.

Comment: Well, I've just discovered that the problem here is Ubuntu's default image viewer. Chrome/Firefox deal with those GIFs just fine. Thank you very much for your time. Now I need to read more about this whole GIF encoding, because I wonder what caused the image viewer to malfunction. Is it encoding used by Go ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing a `File*` to `DecodeAll` rather than something that supports the `io.Reader` interface.

I have adapted your code so that it creates a `bufio.Reader` from the file and then hands that to `DecodeAll` as below:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "image/gif"
)
func main() {
    inputFile , err := os.Open("travolta.gif")
    defer inputFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    r := bufio.NewReader(inputFile)

    g, err := gif.DecodeAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // ... remaining code
}
```

Comment: According to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677235/golang-create-a-io-reader-from-a-local-file os.Open returns and io.Reader. (otherwise it would not compile I think ? ) Moreover i changed the code to your version and it still produces a corrupted gif. Thanks for help though !

Comment: Cheers. You could be right.  I did try with a gif I had around on my PC and it did read and write back a valid gif.  But I did not test your origional code which was a mistake in hind-sight.  However - it leads me to wonder if there is something at play outside of your code, like a corrupt origional Gif?

Comment: I thought about it as well, but I tried a couple of GIFs and every one of them gave a corrupted result .